# Acquiring work rights in UK

Tags: united-kingdom, working-visas, eu-citizens, residence-cards, europe

I possess the following document "Carta di Soggiorno di Familiare di Un Cittadino Dell'Unione" (Residence Card of a family member of a Union Citizen, Italy) issued by the Italian authority. My question is that I  want to work in UK as I have applied for different jobs but the first question I get to asked is if I have working rights? Will I be requiring a work visa ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You posted a [comment](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/123034/19400#comment303228_123034) at [Travel](https://travel.stackexchange.com) that provides some additional information:

> I want to move there but just for the job. No, my parents will be staying in Italy but does my father's sister count as a family member too. She lives in UK and is a British national.

Your aunt does not count as a family member for the purposes of the free movement directive unless you are dependent on her or are a member of her household.  I assume that you are not dependent on her, and it is evident that you are not a member of her household.

Since you want to work in the UK without being accompanied by an EEA national, you will need a regular work visa.

Your Italian residence card allows you to enter the UK without a visa only if you are accompanied by your EEA-national family member.  To work in the UK, you would need a UK residence card, a certificate of application for a UK residence card, or a regular work visa.  You won't be eligible for either of the first two because you will not be living with an EEA-national family member in the UK.

Comment: Would not I be qualifying as an extended family member of an EEA national if I am dependent on them? Right?

Comment: @indexOutOfBounds if you are dependent on them, yes.  Are you dependent on your father's sister?  It looks like you are not, since you presumably are either dependent on your parents or independent.